# Error when using cmake on vk_chopper

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, vulkan

So, I wanted to install Vulkan on ubuntu 16.10. 
I decided to follow this [guide](https://linuxgamecast.com/2016/02/installing-and-testing-vulkan-on-ubuntu/)

Unfortunately at step 9 get to the choppa, I got an error.

cmake .. did not work for me ; this is what happened

Log

ra141@ra141:~$ cd ~/vulkan
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan$ cd gl_vk_chopper
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper$ cd build
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build$ rm -rf ./*
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build$ export VK_SDK_PATH=/home/ra141/vulkan/VulkanSDK
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

---

-- Processing Project gl_vk_chopper:
-- BASE_DIRECTORY = /home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/..
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR = /home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
-- Found GLEW: /home/ra141/vulkan/shared_sources/glew/include
-- Could NOT find GLFW (missing:  GLFW_INCLUDE_DIR GLFW_LIBRARY) 
-- found Glew source code. Using it instead of library
-- VulkanSDK search paths: 
-- VulkanSDK version: 
CMake Warning at /home/ra141/vulkan/shared_sources/cmake/FindVulkanSDK.cmake:133 (message):

```
    VULKANSDK not found. 
    either env. VK_SDK_PATH should be set directly to the right version to use (C:\VulkanSDK\1.0.1.1)
    or you can specify in cmake VULKANSDK_LOCATION to the folder where VulkanSDK versions are put (C:\VulkanSDK)
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/ra141/vulkan/shared_sources/CMakeLists_include.txt:341 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (_add_package_VulkanSDK)

-- Vulkan Root : VULKANSDK_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- Vulkan include : VULKANSDK_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- Vulkan Library : VULKAN_LIB-NOTFOUND
-- Could NOT find VULKANSDK (missing:  VULKANSDK_INCLUDE_DIR VULKAN_LIB) 
-- --> NOT using package VulkanSDK
-- --> using package AntTweakBar
-- Found ANTTWEAKBAR: /usr/include
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
X11_Xcursor_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "gl_vk_chopper" in directory /home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper
    linked by target "gl_vk_chopper" in directory /home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper
    linked by target "shared_sources" in directory /home/ra141/vulkan/shared_sources
X11_Xinerama_LIB (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "gl_vk_chopper" in directory /home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper
    linked by target "gl_vk_chopper" in directory /home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper
    linked by target "shared_sources" in directory /home/ra141/vulkan/shared_sources

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ra141/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build$

some help please?

Comment: and did you do what the error requested? To set `VK_SDK_PATH` or to pass `VULKANSDK_LOCATION` to CMake?

Comment: I actually didn't know how to do that. So how do I do it. Is it export VK_SDK_PATH=/path/to/vulkan/SDK. As suggested by ivan_onys

Comment: What version of Vulcan do you have installed? You will need to point it there and do as @ivan_onys stated, or you can pass it directly to CMake as `cmake .. -DVULKAN_LOCATION=/path/to/Vulkan/SDK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running cmake, run the following command `export VK_SDK_PATH=/path/to/vulkanSDK/version`

Note, that is shall be full path (starting with /)

Be careful to run cmake .. from `build` folder. From the log, seems you start cmake from subfolder of the `build` folder. Better yet, clean it before reruning cmake:

```
cd build
rm -rf ./*
cmake ..
```

Comment: First of all thankyou for the quick reply. So I ave a folder called VulkanSDK which was created when executing the vulkansdk.runfile. So as you said I ran export ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build$ export VK_SDK_PATH=/home/ra141/vulkan/VulkanSDK
ra141@ra141:~/vulkan/gl_vk_chopper/build$ cmake ..
But I still get the same error.

Comment: I cleaned the build folder and did as you said but still no help, I edited by question to show what I did.

Comment: My bad: error message says VK_SDK_PATH must point to particular Vulkan SDK version. There should be folder inside VulkanSDK. Make VK_SDK_PATH point to that folder and let me know, if it helps.